# ASP.NET: How to make a checkbox always unchecked even post-submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox, unchecked

Just started learning how to develop a ASP.NET application, i am puzzled on how to make a checkbox is always unchecked even after form submit where a user tick the checkbox. The checkbox is for acknowledgment that user agrees to the terms and conditions ... and when form submit return some errors I want to display the error message on the screen and keep the checkbox unchecked regardless it was ticked or not.

In my view I have the following:

```
<%: Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.UserAgreement) %>
```

And I have tried both the following in my controller and none of them works:

```
ViewData["UserAgreement"] = false;

return View(new MyModel { UserAgreement = false});
```

Anyone can help on how to achieve what I need? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This bothered me for a long time as well, even explicity setting the values in my model to false did not really solve this problem.  What I found was that it was also checking the value in the ModelState collection.

This is probably not the cleanest solution but this is ultimately what worked for me:

```
private ActionResult DisplayView(string viewName, MyModelClass model)
{
    model.AgreeTerms = false;
    ModelState.Remove("AgreeTerms");

    return View(viewName, model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET MVC CheckBox does not retain its state unless you specifically tell it to do so.

The code you posted above indicates that 'UserAgreement' should be checked (value is TRUE) when the view is returned, not that it should be unchecked.

Unless you specifically set the value of UserAgreement to 'true' before returning the view to the user, the checkbox will be unchecked. Similarly, if your action is receiving a model with the UserAgreement property set to 'true' and you do not set it back to 'false' before returning it to the view, the checkbox will remain checked.

Comment: Hi Nathan, sorry I made a mistake in my post which I have corrected. I meant to assign false as a value. And I still have my checkbox checked if I checked it before submit. Whatever that I do to the checkbox is retained after submit. That's not something that I want ... I would like to have the checkbox always unchecked regardless it was checked or unchecked before submit.

Answer (score 0):

Your value is being saved in the ModelState property. In order to reset the value after a post. You have to cleaer the value in the ModelState property

Comment: Hi Kyle, and how do I do that? I thought my last line of codes did that?

Answer (score 0):

Try `ModelState.Remove("UserAgreement");` before you return the view.